# How can I quit and save Mega Man 11 on the Switch?

Tags: nintendo-switch, mega-man-11

In out household we limit gaming to 30 minute blocks but when we are playing Mega Man 11 on the Switch there is no auto save, so if we just turn off the game we lose all progress.

How can I stop playing, save my progress, and quit Mega Man 11 on the Switch?

Comment: Couldn't you put the switch in sleep mode? It'd keep the game open and paused without the need to save.

Comment: @MatteoTassinari but this would mean that I couldn't play any other games until I completed the whole game.

Comment: Uhm, in general you'd be right, but I don't think that megaman 11 doesn't have any way *at all* to save the game... That'd be really strange! Let me check and get back to you.

Comment: `The save options can be found in the main boss menu, and the option appears after completing a stage or hitting the game over screen` so you should be able to manually save after completing the stage.

Comment: @MatteoTassinari so does that mean there is no way to stop after a checkpoint but before beating the boss and save the game?

Comment: @MatteoTassinari You should post this as an answer.  Comments are ethereal and nebulous things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I have found [online](https://www.gamespot.com/articles/psa-mega-man-11-doesnt-auto-save/1100-6462242/) (I don't own the game, sorry), it seems that

> The save options can be found in the main boss menu, and the option appears after completing a stage or hitting the game over screen.

So it doesn't seem you can save halfway through a level, but only at the end of each one, after beating the boss.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the game by going to the stage select screen, pressing "ZR" and choosing which file you want to save your progress in.